# Devolver posición de un String independiente

Tags: java, java-8

Mi objetivo es que me devuelva el índice de una palabra independiente que esté dentro de un texto, ej:

```
texto: 
raton ratona ra
Palabra para buscar: ra.
ra se encuentra en el índice 14
```

¿Cómo lo podría hacer?

```
static int buscar(String t, String p) {
   int pos = 0;
   if (t.contains(p)) {
       pos = t.indexOf(p);
   }else {
       pos = t.indexOf(p);
   }
    
    
   return pos;
```

Comment: Y cuál es el problema con el código que compartes?

Comment: Ej: rato rata ratoncillo ra. Quiero buscar ra y me devuelve la posición de la subcadena ra de rato en vez de la posición de la cadena ra

Comment: que me devuelve la posición de una subcadena en vez de una cadena independiente...

Comment: Entiendo entiendo, tu quieres buscar la palabra completa "ra" no en donde contenga "ra"... confírmame si es eso para saber si entendí bien

Comment: Claro, eso es..

Comment: Vale. Como sugerencia para esta y futuras oportunidades, todo eso va en la pregunta. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La clase [`Matcher`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Matcher.html) es la que necesitas para lograr lo que quieres, pero hay que seguir varios pasos para usarla.

**1- Crear una instancia de la clase [`Pattern`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)**

Esta representa la expresión regular que permitirá buscar lo que deseas dentro de un texto (en este caso la palabra 'ra').

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\bra\\b");
```

`\\b` representa un delimitador de palabras, como: espacios en blanco, saltos de línea y signos de puntuación. Para poder encontrar palabras completas debemos poner uno de estos símbolos al inicio y otro al final del patrón a buscar (en este caso 'ra'), igual que cuando escribimos cualquier texto.

**2- Obtener una instancia de `Matcher`**

Para esto tenemos que hacer uso del método [`matcher(CharSequence)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#matcher(java.lang.CharSequence)) de la clase `Pattern`. A este método le pasaremos el texto en donde buscarémos la palabra.

```
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("raton ratona ra");
```

**3- Buscar la palabra (si existe) y obtener su ídice inicial**

Para esto le decimos al `matcher` que busque alguna coincidencia de nuestro patrón y si la encuentra le pedimos su índice inicial. En caso de no encontrarla devolvemos `-1` para indicarlo.

```
if (matcher.find()) {
    return matcher.start();
}

return -1;
```

**Solución completa**

```
static int buscar(String texto, String palabra) {
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\b" + palabra + "\\b");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(texto);

    if (matcher.find()) {
       return matcher.start();
    }

    return -1;
}
```

**NOTA FINAL**

Hay dos cosas que me gustaría señalar en tu código:

La primera es que según el texto que pones de ejemplo la palabra 'ra' inicia en el índice 13 no 14.

Lo otro es que, devolver `0` en caso de no encontrar coincidencias es un error conceptual, puesto que este valor representa un índice válido: el inicio de la cadena. Aquí lo correcto sería devolver un valor que no represente un índice válido, para lo cual está generalizado, y de facto se usa, el `-1`.