# Como sustituyo una parte de un String en Java

Tags: java, string

Estoy intentando crear una parte de código que analice una cierta cadena de modo que si encuentra cualquier palabra con el siguiente formato `"</palabraRandom>"` la sustituya por `"<![CDATA[</palabraRandom>]]>"`, esta palabra random estaría entre otras palabras del string y podría tener nombres diferentes, es decir, no va a ser siempre constante, por lo que tengo que encontrar un método que consiga sustituir cualquier cosa que aparezca entre `"</>"`.
¿Alguno tiene alguna idea?

Comment: pon lo q has intentado para poderte ayudar

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/415075/devolver-posici%c3%b3n-de-un-string-independiente entra aqui

Comment: Lo que estás buscando es el método [String#replaceAll(String, String)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,java.lang.String))

Answer (score 1):

**Aqui te tengo un codigo que te puede servir**

```
public static String sustituir(final String frase, final String palabraRandom)
{
    final StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(frase);
    final String palabraBusqueda = "</" + palabraRandom + ">";
    final String palabraFinal = "<![CDATA[</"+ palabraRandom +">]]>";

    int indexOf;
    int index = 0;
    while ((indexOf = builder.indexOf(palabraBusqueda, index)) != -1)
    {
        builder.replace(indexOf, indexOf + palabraBusqueda.length(), palabraFinal);
        index = indexOf + palabraFinal.length();
    }

    return builder.toString();
```

Las pruevas me dan el resultado esperado...

```
@org.junit.Test
public void sustituirTest() {
    String out;
    String frace = "</www></palabraRandom></www></palabraRandom></palabraRandom></www>";
    out = sustituir(frace, "palabraRandom");
    System.out.println(out);
    out = sustituir(out, "www");
    System.out.println(out);
}
```

**Output**

```
</www><![CDATA[</palabraRandom>]]></www><![CDATA[</palabraRandom>]]><![CDATA[</palabraRandom>]]></www>
<![CDATA[</www>]]><![CDATA[</palabraRandom>]]><![CDATA[</www>]]><![CDATA[</palabraRandom>]]><![CDATA[</palabraRandom>]]><![CDATA[</www>]]>
```

Answer (score 0):

tengo otra variante para solucionar el problema

```
public class StringUtils {

    public String replace(final String sentence, final String word) {
        final String wordToSearch = "</".concat(word).concat(">");
        final String wordToReplace = "<![CDATA[</".concat(word).concat(">]]>");

        return sentence.replaceAll(wordToSearch, wordToReplace);
    }
}
```

Basicamente el metodo recibe por parametros la frase a revisar y cual es la palabra que debe reemplazarse. Despues genero el tag que tengo que buscar junto con lo que deberia haber en su lugar y utilizo el metodo replaceAll de la clase String que reemplaza todas las ocurrencias de la misma.

Comment: Lo tengo en cuenta para futuras respuestas, pero me parecio bastante simple el codigo